# Position output from Google Apps Script to the right of column A

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet script that reads values listed in column A with this code

```
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("master").getDataRange().getValues()

for(n=2;n<values.length;++n){
var data = values[n][0] ; // read values in column A

}
```

With this data in column A I make api calls and store the data from the API requests in a multidimensional array 'resultRow'

How can I output resultRow in column B,C,D,E,.... so that each row that corresponds with its product # is positioned next to it?

```
| column A |    column B    |    column C    |    column D    |     column E   |
| 79327492 | resultRow[0,0] | resultRow[0,1] | resultRow[0,2] |
| 78828388 | resultRow[1,0] | resultRow[1,1] |                 
| 74629642 | resultRow[2,0] | resultRow[2,1] | resultRow[2,2] | resultRow[2,3] |
```

I've tried

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("master").getRange(3,2,rows,columns); // rows = amount of rows, columns = amount of columns 
range.setValues([resultRow]);
```

But I keep getting this error: 
Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 14

Comment: If I understand well, the length of each row might be different every time ? in that case you have to normalize your result array so that each sub array has exactly the same length.

Comment: multidimensional array 'resultRow'? If it is already a multi-dimensional array you do not need the brackets in you're setValues( resultRow) . This assumes that all your inner arrays are the same length. If not you should follow Serge's lead.

Comment: You're correct. I was trying out different things, and at first I had a "cannot convert array to object" error, which i was I added the extra brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in your sheet layout, the length of the rows can be different from one row to another.
`setValues(2D-Array)` requires that each element in the 2D array has exactly the same length so you have to modify your result array so that it meets the requirements.

This can be done in many ways, below is one possible (although not the most elegant) way :

*The first function testArray is simply there to create a non homogeneous 2D array to illustrate and provide a use case : it gets non empty values in a sheet and collects it in a 2D array, the sheet I used had a lot of empty cells and random data in it...)*

```
function testArrays(){
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log('original array : \n\n'+JSON.stringify(values)+'\n');
  Logger.log('row Length = '+values[0].length+'\n');
  var resultArray = [];
  for(var n=0;n<values.length;n++){
    var rowArray = [];
    for(var m=0;m<values[0].length;m++){
      if(values[n][m] != ''){
        rowArray.push(values[n][m]);
      }
    }
    resultArray.push(rowArray);
  }
  Logger.log('wrong array : \n'+JSON.stringify(resultArray)+'\n');
  resultArray = normalizeTwoDimArray(resultArray,values[0].length);
  Logger.log('normalized array : \n'+JSON.stringify(resultArray));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().setValues(resultArray)
} 

function normalizeTwoDimArray(array,maxLength){
  for(var n=0;n<array.length;n++){
    if(array[n].length<maxLength){
      for(var m = array[n].length ; m < maxLength ; m++){
        array[n].push('');
      }
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify for others, the "Incorrect range height" was caused by an error in my script (I ended up with 1 row in the array due to a typo). Once I fixed that I used the array normalization function to normalize the array, which solved my uneven row length issue. Thank you Serge!